# Somar "Input List" em Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, html5, script

Estou com algumas dificuldades em JavaScript. Eu desejo somar alguns campos do meu "Input List" e multiplicar outros ao clicar em um "Botão Calcular", assim informando um valor em um "Input Text". Mais nada do que faço tem dado certo, por favor se alguém puder me ajudar.

```
    Preço:
    <input type="text" name="preco"><br />
    <button>Comprar</button>

    <form id="pizza3">
        <p>Tamanho da Pizza:</p>
        <input list="tmhpizza" name="tmhpizza" required />
            <datalist id="tmhpizza">
            <option value="Brotinho">R$20,00</option>
            <option value="Pequena">R$45,00</option>
            <option value="Média">R$70,00</option>
            <option value="Grande">R$95,00</option>
            <option value="Gigante">R$120,00</option>
            </datalist>
        <p>Quantidade de Pizzas:</p>
        <input list="qntpizza" name="qntpizza" required />
            <datalist id="qntpizza">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            </datalist>
        <p>Tamanho do Refrigerante:</p>
        <input list="tmhrefri" name="tmhrefri" required />
            <datalist id="tmhrefri">
            <option value="350ml">R$4,50</option>
            <option value="750ml">R$6,30</option>
            <option value="1L">R$8,10</option>
            <option value="2L">R$9,90</option>
            <option value="2,5L">R$11,70</option>
            </datalist>
        <p>Quantidade de Refrigerante:</p>
        <input list="qntrefri" name="qntrefri" required />
            <datalist id="qntrefri">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            </datalist><br />
    <input type="button" name="voltar" value="Voltar" />
    <button>Calcular</button>
```

Comment: Podes colocar o código que fizeste? como estás a gerar esse HTML? dá para adicionar informação no HTML ou já o recebes "feito" e não podes alterar?

Comment: Usar `datalist` complica um bocado, um `select` seria melhor pois o `datalist` não tem por exemplo `selectedIndex` e é dificil tirar o `innerHTML`. Se responderes às minhas duvidas em cima posso ajudar-te melhor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu faria isso de outra maneira... deves ter em conta que tendo o HTML certo já quando vem do servidor facilita muito a parte de JavaScript.

Eu sugiro usar `select` em vêz de `datalist`. O `select` é feito para este tipo de opções/uso, o `datalist` é pensado para outros fins e é dificil ler o `value` e o `innerHTML` do `datalist` selecionado.

Se colocares no HTML uma referência sobre que `select` é o multiplicador de outro isso facilita muito também. Colocar o preco no value também é prático. Se precisares saber a descição do produto no servidor sugiro [usares um JSON no value desta maneira](http://jsfiddle.net/gu0001kj/1/).

Daí que sugiro este codigo que dou no exemplo em baixo. As principais diferênças é usar select em vêz de datalist e usar um campo `data-rel="" onde coloco o ID do select que deve ser multiplicado por esta seleção.

```js
var calcular = document.getElementById('calcular');
calcular.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var selects = document.querySelectorAll('select[data-rel]');
    var precos = [].map.call(selects, function (select) {
        var multiplicador = parseInt(select.value, 10);
        var precoProduto = document.getElementById(select.dataset.rel).value;
        return parseFloat(precoProduto) * multiplicador;
    });
    document.querySelector('input[name="preco"]').value = precos.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
});
```

```css
div {
    padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<form id="pizza3">
        <p>Tamanho da Pizza:</p>
        <select id="tmhpizza">
            <option value="20">Brotinho - R$20,00</option>
            <option value="45">Pequena - R$45,00</option>
            <option value="70">Média - R$70,00</option>
            <option value="95">Grande - R$95,00</option>
            <option value="120">Gigante - R$120,00</option>
        </select>
        <p>Quantidade de Pizzas:</p>
        <select id="qntpizza" data-rel="tmhpizza">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
        <p>Tamanho do Refrigerante:</p>
        <select id="tmhrefri">
            <option value="4.5">350ml - R$4,50</option>
            <option value="6.3">750ml - R$6,30</option>
            <option value="8.1">1L - R$8,10</option>
            <option value="9.9">2L - R$9,90</option>
            <option value="11.7">2,5L - R$11,70</option>
        </select>
        <p>Quantidade de Refrigerante:</p>
        <select id="qntrefri" data-rel="tmhrefri">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
        <p>Preço:</p>
        <input readonly="true" id="total" type="text" name="preco">
        <p>
            <button type="button" id="calcular">Calcular</button>
            <button type="submit">Comprar</button>
            <button type="button">Voltar</button>
        </p>
    </form>
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gu0001kj/

Comment: Ficou ótimo, mas infelizmente não posso utilizar Jquery no meu código, isso que tem dificultado tudo.

Comment: @LarissaMourullo não há jQuery na minha resposta...

Comment: Consegui fazer pegar o código, mas ele só funciona se eu colocar a tag script no final da página, e preciso seguir as regras da W3C que impede de fazer isso. Você saberia dizer porque?

Comment: @LarissaMourullo não tem mal colocar o script no final do body. Se quiseres colocar no head podes usar `window.onload = function(){ ...codigo...}`.

Comment: @LarissaMourullo vi que fizeste uma pergunta sobre colocar o código na head. A resposta do Zuul é excelente, bem aceite.